# "Hook" (callback) for Night Light?

Tags: 22.04, display, system-settings

I'd like to sync a Zigbee "smart" light to the [Night Light](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-night-light.html.en) settings (with 22.04 LTS).
What are the internals of this function and is there a way to run a program on any changes or monitor it (poll state)?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is Zigbee, Night Light, etc?

Comment: @Pilot6 Night Light (link added) adjusts display color temperature by sun position or manual schedule. Zigbee is a common radio control system for "smart" home appliances and lights (home automation), but merely mentioned for context - it has no direct relevance. I'd like to have the computer change a "smart" light's color temperature along with the display.